# I can't fire Facebook like box FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', 

Tags: facebook

I do not receive a callback when the like button in the like box is clicked. It works with normal like button, but not with the like button in the like box.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only like button that fires an event is the XFBML version.  The HTML5 and IFRAME versions do not return a callback.  Use the FB.Subscribe to catch the events and edge.create and edge.remove for the like and unlike callbacks respectively.

Comment: Jesus, it'd be nice if that was in the docs for `edge.create`. Thanks!